# How do I hide the full module path when raising a custom exception?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a custom exception `CustomException` for my package `foo` defined in `module/submodule/exceptions.py`:

```py
# foo/module/submodule/exceptions.py
class CustomException(Exception):
    ...
```

If I raise this error, the full module path is included in the error message:

```py
from foo.module.submodule.exceptions import CustomException

raise CustomException("hello")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
foo.module.submodule.exceptions.CustomException: hello
```

I would like to hide the module path from the exception, as I consider this an implementation detail that might change whenever I decide to refactor something. I would like the final exception message to read:

```
foo.CustomException: hello
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236383/cleaning-up-interal-path-and-stack-levels-in-customexception-messages-raised?

Comment: Most of the time, you define custom exceptions to allow for easier-to-read error handling, not to manipulate the appearance of a traceback should that exception not be caught.

Comment: If you're going to make your exception show up as `foo.CustomException`, remember to make it *actually available* as `foo.CustomException` too.

Answer (score -1):

Found out you can achieve this somewhat by renaming `self.__class__.__module__` of the Exception:

### Custom Exception Class

```py
class CustomException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message: str):
        """
        A custom exception
        """
        message = f"My custom message\nERROR: {message}"
        self.message = message
        self.__class__.__module__ = "foo"
        super(CustomException, self).__init__(message)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message
```

### Raising it

```py
raise CustomException("some reason")
```

### Output

```
foo.CustomException: My custom message
ERROR: some reason
```

### Beware

We are renaming private variables that is considered bad practice. It seems to work fine. Use at your own risk. I do not know of an alternative